# Create a file with the concatenated information of all files that start with "file_excel", in chronological order

Tags: ksh, cat

my system:

```
Linux 2.6.18-406.el5 #1 SMP Fri May 1 10:37:57 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my shell: `/bin/ksh`

My issue:
I want to create a file: data_excel with the information of the other files which start its filename with "file_excel".
The information must be concatenated in chronological order(modification time).

Comment: does "chronological order" mean of the "file_excel*" modification times, or of data inside those files (in which case, we need to see/know what those look like)

Comment: I mean the modification time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat $(ls -tr file_excel*) > data_excel
```